# CSS :hover selector not working on a button

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to get the button to have a fading effect (change border and text color), but the hover selector is just not working. I've tried to fix this for an hour with no avail.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://www.ecopetit.cat/wpic/mpic/1-16867_preview-wallpaper-new-york-usa-night-skyscrapers-new.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #999;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fadebutton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.fadebutton:hover,
.fadebutton:active {
  color: #66d8ed;
  border-color: #66d8ed;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="script.js"></script>

<a class="fadebutton" href="www.google.com">Change color</a>
```

Comment: It's working exactly how it's supposed to.

Comment: I put the code into an executable snippet and it seems to work correctly (fading from white to light blue) - I'll add a different bg-colour so the link is visible from the start

Comment: Make sure the stylesheet you are importing is not overriding the custome style you are applying above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the *text* of the button to also fade colour, then you could add a transition to that property as well.  So instead of just,

`transition: border-color 0.4s ease-in;`

you can also have:

```
transition: border-color 0.4s ease-in;
transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
```

**See demo below:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://www.ecopetit.cat/wpic/mpic/1-16867_preview-wallpaper-new-york-usa-night-skyscrapers-new.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #999;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fadebutton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;  
  transition: color 0.4s ease-out;
}

.fadebutton:hover{
  color: #66d8ed;  
  border-color: #66d8ed;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease-in;
}

.fadebutton:hover *{
  transition: color 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="script.js"></script>

<a class="fadebutton" href="www.google.com">Change color</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the background color of the body so your button appears
the hover selector is working fine its just color problem! 
Try this code and change it to meet your needs , hope I helped.

```css
   body {
  margin: 0;
 background-color:black;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.fadebutton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color:white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.fadebutton:hover,
.fadebutton:active {
  color: #66d8ed;
  border-color: #66d8ed;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Kell</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fadebutton" href="www.google.com">Change color</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just declare transition all at .fadebutton class, then on the .fadebutton:hover,.fadebutton:active I would declare the change I wanted to make like below for example.

```
    .fadebutton {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
padding: 8px;
color: #fff;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: white;
text-align: center;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.fadebutton:hover,
.fadebutton:active {
color: #66d8ed;
border-color: #66d8ed;
}
```

If you wanted 2 properties to behave differently I would specify the transitions independently like this.

```
       .fadebutton {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
padding: 8px;
color: #fff;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: white;
text-align: center;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color 0.3s ease-in;
transition: border-color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.fadebutton:hover,
.fadebutton:active {
color: #66d8ed;
border-color: #66d8ed;
}
```